# Sharing promises between modules vs having multiple promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, repository-pattern, q

I am implementing **Node.js** logic with controllers and repository using Kris Kowal's **Q** library. I have a feeling that the way I use promises in the example below is not correct. But I can't find any guidance on proper pattern how to use promises through multiple layers or functions.

Am I doing it right? What's the proper way implementing this logic?

*// Module: Repository*

```
exports.findOne = function (query) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.query(query, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

*// Module: User*

```
var isEmailAvailable = function (value) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    Repository.findOne({email: value})
        .then(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                if (self.id === user.id) {
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.resolve(false);
                }
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};

this.save = function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    isEmailAvailable(this.email)
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                Repository.upsert(self)
                    .then(function (user) {
                        deferred.resolve(user); //--- Yey!!!
                    }).fail(function () {
                        deferred.reject('Account save error')
                    });
            } else {
                deferred.reject('The email is already in use');
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            deferred.reject('Account validation error')
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a feeling that the way I use promises is not correct

Yes, you use the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) a lot. [Promises do **chain**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), which means that you simply can `return` values and even promises from your `then` callback, and the `.then()` call will yield a promise for those return values. And when you `throw`, the result promise will be rejected.

Your usage of deferreds in repository module is correct, as the `db.query` api needs to be [promisified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). But the user module can be shrank heavily, you don't need to use any deferreds when you already have promises.

```
function isEmailAvailable(value) {
    return Repository.findOne({email: value})
    .then(function (user) {
        return !user || self.id === user.id;
    });
}

this.save = function() {
    return isEmailAvailable(this.email)
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            return Repository.upsert(self)
            .then(null, function(err) {
                throw new Error('Account save error');
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('The email is already in use');
        }
    }, function(err) {
        throw new Error('Account validation error');
    });
};
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @Roamer-1888, using [exceptions for control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572):

```
function isEmailAvailable(value) {
    return Repository.findOne({email: value})
    .then(function (user) {
        if (user && self.id !== user.id)
            throw new Error('The email is already in use');
    }, function(err) {
        throw new Error('Account validation error');
    });
}

this.save = function() {
    return isEmailAvailable(this.email)
    .then(function () {
        return Repository.upsert(self)
        .then(null, function(err) {
            throw new Error('Account save error');
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: If `isEmailAvailable()` was to employ the success/error paths instead of sending true/false down the success path, then I think you will find that `this.save()` also becomes dramatically simpler.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Have a look at my edit. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Bergi, yes, essentially so. I would probably leave out the 'Account validation error' throw as it would potentially mask better error messages thrown by `Repository.findOne()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Yeah, maybe that would be better, but I wanted to stay equivalent in behaviour to OPs function, where it is *supposed* to mask errors thrown by `findOne()`.

Comment: Yup, cool. Armed with your explanation, the OP can choose which way to go.

Comment: Thank you @Roamer-1888 and @Bergi! This is exactly what I needed! That last "aha! gotcha!" piece of a puzzle!